# How do I return promise to satisfy the directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, es6-promise

I have the following code and I have tried just bout everything to return a promise that would work with the directive. I have even tried returning the response data and return $q.when(data) and nothing. Ive tried reading on promises and this one is a bit different then Ive read. Something I'm missing?

```
myApp.controller('smsCtrl', function($scope){
        $scope.sendSMS = function(){
            let sms = {'number': $scope.number  ,'message': $scope.message};
            serviceNameHere.sendSMS(sms).then(function(response){
                $scope.smsSuccessMsg = "Message Sent Successfully";
            }, function(response){
                $scope.smsErrorMsg = response.data['message'];
            });
    };         
})

myApp.directive('onClickDisable', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      onClickDisable: '&'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.bind('click', function() {
        element.prop('disabled',true);
        scope.onClickDisable().finally(function() {
          element.prop('disabled',false);
        })
      });
    }
  };
});
```

The following html

```
<div ng-controller="smsCtrl">
<-- field inputs here --></-->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" on-click-disable="sendSMS()">SEND</button>
</div>
```

[JSfiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/jsjmztpy/19/)

Comment: Your fiddle is unavailable, also, what are you trying to do? re-enable it again after the request went through?

Comment: `to return a promise` - hint: if you want a function to return anything (even a promise), you'll need a `return` somewhere

Comment: Once you fix the fiddle link, you may as well remove it ... *ReferenceError: angular is not defined* - pointless to have a fiddle that fails the basics

Comment: your fiddle is still broken..line 41 needs to be `}]);` and you need to inject `serviceNameHere` into your controller

Comment: @JaromandaX  I have tried returning just bout everything.

Comment: I posted the code in jfiddle to show you kinda what I got going on, I know I'm missing something extremely easy, thats why I didnt figure creating a complete working jfiddle. But if its necessary I will work on that,

Comment: here is a somewhat fixed fiddle..the one you posted is still broken... https://jsfiddle.net/jsjmztpy/19/

Comment: this is the error im getting, TypeError: scope.onClickDisable(...) is undefined aswell on my end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have a special directive for this. Simply use `ng-disabled` and `ng-click`:

```
<div ng-controller="smsCtrl">
    <!-- field inputs here -->
    <button ng-click="sendSMS()" ng-disabled="pendingSMS">
      SEND
    </button>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
myApp.controller('smsCtrl', function($scope, serviceNameHere){
        $scope.sendSMS = function(){
            let sms = {'number': $scope.number  ,'message': $scope.message};
            $scope.pendingSMS = true;
            serviceNameHere.sendSMS(sms).then(function(response){
                $scope.smsSuccessMsg = "Message Sent Successfully";
            }, function(response){
                $scope.smsErrorMsg = response.data['message'];
            }).finally(function() {
                $scope.pendingSMS = false;
            });
    };         
})
```

When the SMS message starts, the controller sets the `pendingSMS` flag to disable the <kbd>Send</kbd> button. When the service completes, the flag is reset and the button is re-enabled.